# Multiple Sharded Databases Hibernate Transactions

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, transactionmanager

I have a spring based tomcat service. I use annotations based hibernate mapping and I have multiple sharded databases. All the sharded databases have same tables say Student. I want to implement transaction on them using `@Transactional` annotation.

```
@Autowired
List<SessionFactory> sessionFactoryList;

@Transactional
public insertStudentBatch(List<Student> students) {

}
```

Now I want to insert entire batch. If any error occurs, I want all of them to roll back. What is the best way to do that? Can I write multiple `TransactionManager` qualifier like `@Transactional("txManager1", "txManager2")`?

Comment: Why don't you try instead of asking if you can try?

Comment: Its not working. I am asking if I can set it up anyhow to work. When I am trying to insert in 2 DBs using @Transactional, it is inserting only in one of them.

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately the spring `@Transactional` annotation is specific to a single transaction manager and does not behave in the desire you described.

It seems to me what you would likely want is a JTA transaction for 2PC commit where you basically start a master JTA transaction and then for each `SessionFactory`, you invoke each of the specific transaction managers for your shards and perform your operations.

```
 @Service
 public class StudentBatchServiceImpl implements StudentBatchService {
   @Autowired List<StudentService> studentServices;
   @Transactional(value = "jtaTransactionManager")
   public void storeStudents(List<Student> students) {
     for(StudentService service : studentServices) 
       service.storeStudents(students);
   }
 }

 public interface StudentService {
   void storeStudents(List<Student> students);
 }

 public abstract AbstractStudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {
   protected void storeStudents(EntityManager em, List<Student> students) {
     for(Student student : students) {
       em.persist(student);
     }
   }
 }

 @Service
 public class Shard1StudentServiceImpl extends AbstractStudentServiceImpl {
   @PersistenceContext(name = "shard1")
   private EntityManager entityManager;
   @Override
   @Transactional(value = "shard1TransactionManager")
   public void storeStudents(List<Student> students) {
     storeStudents(entityManager, students);
   }
 }
```

There may be some other ways to handle this without a 2PC commit setup with JTA, but tyically in container managed transactions (like JBoss, WebLogic, etc); this would be the approach.

As a side bar, if you're already down the spring path I might suggest you check out `spring-batch`.  It provides a decent baseline for batch like operations for a plethora of use cases.   What I described above is a poor-mans implementation of one case inside `spring-batch`.

**UPDATE**

If you want to avoid having to create multiple shard class implementations with annotation details, you could resort to XML configuration and have a single class implementation:

```
 <bean id="shard1" class="default.ShardStudentServiceImpl">
   <property name="entityManager" ref="shard1EntityManager" />
   <property name="transactionManager" ref="shard1TransactionManager" />
 </bean>
```

The only difference here is that you have to define your 25 shards in XML and then you have to write your own code to start, commit, and manage the transaction inside your `ShardStudentServiceImpl` class.

Using the abstract base class in conjunction with annotations in the final implementations shown above my update arrives at the same destination.  In fact, if you look at `spring-batch`, you'll notice their batch configuration follows a similar premise with specifying the entity manager and transaction managers as input properties to a single class.

Comment: What is meant by - `// Each instance here has their own EntityManager/SessionFactory/PersistenceContext
`? If I have 25 databases, do I have to implement it 25 times? Can you please make it a little more clear?

Comment: Yes, you will have multiple implementations of `AbstractStudentServiceImpl` because each implemented service describes the contract between a persistence context instance and a specific transaction manager instance.  See my update.